# Is Tolkien's Middle Earth flat?

Tags: geometry, ring-theory, noneuclidean-geometry

In the first introductory chapter of his book *Gravitation and cosmology: principles and applications of the general theory of relativity* Steven Weinberg discusses the origin of non-euclidean geometries and the "inner properties" of surfaces.

He mentions that distances between all pairs of 4 points on a flat surface satisfy a particular relation:

$$\begin{align}
0 &= d_{12}^4d_{34}^2 + d_{13}^4d_{24}^2 + d_{14}^4d_{23}^2 + d_{23}^4d_{14}^2 + d_{24}^4d_{13}^2 + d_{34}^4 d_{12}^2\\
&\phantom{{}=} + d_{12}^2 d_{23}^2 d_{31}^2 + d_{12}^2 d_{24}^2d_{41}^2 + d_{13}^2d_{34}^2d_{41}^2 + d_{23}^2d_{34}^2d_{42}^2\\
&\phantom{{}=} - d_{12}^2d_{23}^2d_{34}^2- d_{13}^2d_{32}^2d_{24}^2 - d_{12}^2d_{24}^2d_{43}^2 -   d_{14}^2d_{42}^2d_{23}^2\\
&\phantom{{}=} - d_{13}^2d_{34}^2d_{42}^2 - d_{14}^2d_{43}^2d_{32}^2 - d_{23}^2d_{31}^2d_{14}^2 - d_{21}^2d_{13}^2d_{34}^2\\
&\phantom{{}=} - d_{24}^2d_{41}^2d_{13}^2 - d_{21}^2d_{14}^2d_{43}^2 - d_{31}^2d_{12}^2d_{24}^2 - d_{32}^2d_{21}^2d_{14}^2
\end{align}$$

and then presents the reader with the map of Tolkien's Middle Earth with distances between four cities indicated:

- $d$(Hobbiton, Erebor) = 813 mi
- $d$(Erebor, Dagorlad) = 735 mi
- $d$(Dagorlad, City of Corsairs) = 780 mi
- $d$(City of Corsairs, Hobbiton) = 1112 mi
- $d$(Hobbiton, Dagorlad) = 960 mi
- $d$(Erebor, City of Corsairs) = 1498 mi

Substituting these numbers into the rhs of the formula I got $588330312698242944 \ \rm{mi}^6 \approx (915.384 \ \rm{mi})^6$.

So my questions are:

1. If this is correct then what is the Middle Earth: surface of a ball or a hyperboloid? Is it possible to find its radius?
2. How did Weinberg get this relation? He just writes that it's "easy to show".

Comment: There is a relation between the mutual distances of four points $a, b, c, d$ in plane, which goes roughly as follows: The Gram matrix of the vectors $b-a, c-a, d-a$ has determinant $0$ (because its rows are linearly dependent), but can also be written in terms of these distances (or, rather, their squares, since $x^T y = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\left|\left|x+y\right|\right|^2-\left|\left|x\right|\right|^2-\left|\left|y\right|\right|^2\right)$), and so we get a relation between these distances. I guess it's your relation, since it should be the only one.

Comment: why do we have, for example, $d_{12}$ in the first bit and $d_{21}$ in the last - is there a difference when squared?

Comment: Curious! I had said that Tolkien probably drew a map on a paper and took the measures there. It should be flat. But it isn't!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I've written the formula exactly as it is written in the book, I believe there is no difference.

Comment: The  relationship is equivalent to the vanishing of the [Cayler Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry#Cayley.E2.80.93Menger_determinants).

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2\\
1 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2\\
1 & d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0 & d_{34}^2\\
1 & d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$ which is proportional to the square of the volume of a tetrahedron given the length of edges.

Comment: seeing as this is Tolkien, according to AD&D, what is it's alignment?

Comment: See http://www.planet-tolkien.com/board/7/3499/0/accurate-distances and http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-95863.html. It seems that these numbers are not actually from Tolkien. I personally don't remember reading any distances in miles in the books; certainly not with four-digit accuracy.

Comment: Those old-timey books give distances in "leagues".  My dictionary says a league is about three miles.

Comment: @GEdgar it wouldn't matter as all distances would be multiplied by the same number if you change the measuring unites

Comment: 1) The middle earth isn't flat b/c the corr CM determinant non-zero $. 2) If I didn't make any mistake, the middle earth is pretty small. The given distances can be realized as geodesic distances on a sphere of radius 693.66mi.

Comment: @achillehui How did you estimate the radius?

Comment: Assume the $4$ cities $p_i$ lie on a sphere with radius $R$. Let $\theta_{ij} = \frac{d_{ij}}{R}$ and $\phi_{i,jk} = \angle p_j p_i p_k$. We know

$$\phi_{i,jk} = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos \theta_{jk} - \cos\theta_{ij}\cos\theta_{ik}}{\sin\theta_{ij}\sin\theta_{ik}}\right)$$

The three $\phi$ angles attached to a city $p_i$ are not independent. Take $p_1$ as an example.  For a suitable choice of $\pm$, we have
$$\pm \phi_{1,23} \pm \phi_{1,34} \pm \phi_{1,24} = 0 \text{ or } 2\pi$$
What I do is numerically search for a $R$ which allow a relation of this form in every city.

Comment: @achillehui I was able to reproduce your $R$ by considering that first city was on the pole of a sphere, second at $(\theta_2,0)$ (spherical coordinates), third at $(\theta_3,\phi_3)$ and fourth at $(\theta_4, \phi_4)$. Then I used that for any two points $\cos (d_{ik}/R) = \cos \theta_i\cos \theta_k + \sin\theta_i \sin \theta_k\cos(\phi_i-\phi_k)$. And then solved numerically 6 equations for 6 unknowns. This is basically the same method as yours. I got $R=693$, second city at $(67°, 0)$, third at $(79°, 62°)$, fourth at $(92°, 126°)$. Please post your answer as the Answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ring theory tag is cute.

Comment: Since @joriki brought up the accuracy of the distances, I thought I'd check how sensitive the problem is to rounding. Could the apparent non-flatness be a result of someone getting a ones'-place digit wrong? The answer is no: at least one of the distances has to change by at least $26.3$ miles. The "nearest" flat configuration has distances $839.3$, $761.3$, $806.3$, $1138.3$, $933.7$, and $1471.7$ miles.

Comment: @Rahul, "nearest" means that you change distances to $d'_{ij} = d_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$ and find those $\epsilon_{ij}$ that minimze $\sum_{i<j} \epsilon^2_{ij}$?

Comment: It minimizes $\max|d'_{ij}-d_{ij}|$. I should have said "the corresponding flat configuration" related to the assertion in my previous sentence.

Comment: Related (I believe): Section 3 of [Schoenberg, I. J. (1935), *Remarks to Maurice Frechet’s Article ``Sur La Definition Axiomatique D’Une Classe D’Espace Distances Vectoriellement Applicable Sur L’Espace De Hilbert*, The Annals of Mathematics, 36(3), 724. doi:10.2307/1968654](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968654). But strangely, Schoenberg's conditions for the given numbers to be spherical distances of a bunch of points on a sphere are a set of inequalities, so one should expect the radius of a sphere to be only bound to an interval, not determined up to finitely many values?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Overview**

- Is the middle-earth flat? NO.
- Can the middle-earth lies on the surface of a ball?
  YES - In fact there are two radii that work.
- How about the surface of a hyperboloid? NO.

---

**Part I** - Is middle-earth flat?

That complicated expression from Weinberg is proportional to something
called [Cayley Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry#Cayley.E2.80.93Menger_determinants).

$$\Delta_{CM}(d_{ij}) \stackrel{def}{=} \det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & d_{12}^2 & d_{13}^2 & d_{14}^2\\
1 & d_{12}^2 & 0 & d_{23}^2 & d_{24}^2\\
1 & d_{13}^2 & d_{23}^2 & 0 & d_{34}^2\\
1 & d_{14}^2 & d_{24}^2 & d_{34}^2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Using the fact $d_{ij} = d_{ji}$, one can show that Weinberg's expression is simply $-\frac12 \Delta_{CM}(d_{ij})$.

Given any tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with vertices $\vec{x}_1, \ldots, \vec{x}_4$. It is known that the volume $V$ of that tetrahedron can be computed
by following formula.

$$288 V^2 = \Delta_{CM}( |\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j| )\tag{*1}$$

Conversely, if we are given a set of $6$ positive numbers $d_{ij}, 1 \le i < j \le 4$. It can be realized as the edge lengths of a tetrahedron when

- the edge lenghts satisfy triangular inequalities.
- and the corresponding Cayley-Menger determinant $\Delta_{CM}(d_{ij})$ is non-negative.
  (positive if we want a non-degenerate tetrahedron).

For a proof of this, please see the paper [Edge lengths determining tetrahedrons](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=64&iss=4&rank=4) by Karl Wirth and Andre S. Dreiding.

Back to the question whether the middle-earth is flat.

If it is flat, then we can embed the $4$ cities congruently in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The corresponding tetrahedron will be degenerate and its volume vanishes. Using $(*1)$,
we find the distances between the cities need to satisfy $\Delta_{CM}( d_{ij} ) = 0$.

However, if we substitute the supplied distances into the defining formula for $\Delta_{CM}(d_{ij})$, we get a negative number! This means the middle-earth is not only non-flat, we can't realize the supplied distances as Euclidean distances in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

**Part II** - Can the middle-earth lies on the surface of a ball?

The answer is YES, there are two radii $571.164553{\rm mi}$ and $693.660559{\rm mi}$ that work. For these two radii, we can realize the supplied distances on a sphere of that radius.

Before we start, let us look at a simplified problem:

> Given any $6$ numbers $\alpha_{ij} \in (0,\pi)$, $0 \le i < j \le 3$ satisfying an appropriate set of triangular inequalities. What is the extra condition
>   one need to satisfy in order to have $4$ point $q_0,\ldots q_3$ on the unit sphere $S^2$ such that the geodesic distance $d(q_i,q_j) = \alpha_{ij}$ ?

Parametrize the unit sphere $S^2$ by polar coordinates

$$[0,\pi] \times [-\pi,\pi) \ni (\theta,\phi) \quad\mapsto\quad (\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta ) \in S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$$

Let $i, j, k$ be any permutation of $1, 2, 3$ such that $j < k$ and define
a bunch of variables:
$$
\begin{cases}
\theta_i &= \alpha_{0i},\\
\psi_i   &= \alpha_{jk}
\end{cases},
\quad
\begin{cases}
b_i &= \cos\psi_i\\
c_i &= \cos\theta_i,\\
s_i &= \sin\theta_i,\\
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
e_i = \frac{b_i - c_j c_k}{s_j s_k} = \frac{\cos\psi_i - \cos\theta_j\cos\theta_k}{\sin\theta_j\sin\theta_k}
$$
We can fulfill the requirement on $\alpha_{01}, \alpha_{02}, \alpha_{03}$ by placing 
$$q_0 \text{ at } (0,0),\quad
  q_1 \text{ at } (\theta_1, 0 ),\quad
  q_2 \text{ at } (\theta_2, \phi_{12} )\quad\text{ and }\quad
  q_3 \text{ at } (\theta_3, \phi_{13} )
$$
for some $\phi_{12}$, $\phi_{13}$ to be determined.

To fulfill the requirement of $\alpha_{12}$ and $\alpha_{13}$, we need

$$\begin{cases}
b_3 &= \cos\alpha_{12} = \cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\phi_{12} = c_1 c_2 + s_1 s_2\cos\phi_{12}\\
b_2 &= \cos\alpha_{13} = \cos\theta_1\cos\theta_3 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_3\cos\phi_{13} = c_1 c_3 + s_1 s_3\cos\phi_{13}
\end{cases}
$$
This is equivalent to $\begin{cases}
\cos\phi_{12} &= e_3\\
\cos\phi_{13} &= e_2\\
\end{cases}
$ and we can do this by setting $
\begin{cases}
\phi_{12} &=  +  \cos^{-1}e_3\\
\phi_{13} &= \pm \cos^{-1}e_2
\end{cases}
$.

One may worry whether $\phi_{12}, \phi_{13}$ defined in this manner is well defined. It turns out when the appropriate set of triangular inequalities is satisfied, all the $|e_i| \le 1$. So $\phi_{12}$ is well defined and up to a sign, so does $\phi_{13}$.

To fix the sign of $\phi_{13}$ and fulfill the requirement $\alpha_{23}$, we need

$$b_1 = \cos\alpha_{23} = \cos\theta_2\cos\theta_3 + \sin\theta_2\sin\theta_3\cos(\phi_{12} - \phi_{13}) = c_2 c_3 + s_2 s_3\cos(\phi_{12} - \phi_{13})$$
This is equivalent to 
$$\begin{align}
e_1 
&= \cos(\phi_{12} - \phi_{13}) 
= \cos\phi_{12}\cos\phi_{13} + \sin\phi_{12}\sin\phi_{13}\\
&= e_3 e_2 + \text{sign}(\phi_{13})\sqrt{1-e_3^2}\sqrt{1-e_2^2}
\end{align}\tag{*2}
$$
This leads to following condition on $\alpha_{ij}$

$$(e_1 - e_2 e_3)^2 = (1-e_3^2)(1-e_2^2) 
\iff
1 - e_1^2 - e_2^2 - e_3^2 + 2e_1e_2e_3 = 0\tag{*3}$$

Working backwards, it is not hard to verify if $\alpha_{ij}$ satisfies $(*3)$, we can find a sign of $\phi_{13}$ to satisfy $(*2)$. 
What this means is $(*3)$ is the necessary and sufficient condition we are seeking
for placing the $4$ points $q_i$ on unit sphere.

Apply this to our problem of placing the 4 cities on a sphere of radius $R$.

Let $q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3$ be the locations of
"Hobbiton", "City of Corsairs", "Dagorlad" and "Erebor" respectively.
We have
$$( d_{01}, d_{02}, d_{03}, d_{23}, d_{13}, d_{12} ) = ( 1112, 960, 813, 735, 1498, 780 )$$

Let $\alpha_{ij} = \frac{d_{ij}}{R}$ and compute the value of the expression
$$1 - e_1^2 - e_2^2 - e_3^2 + 2e_1 e_2 e_3$$
as a function for $R \in [\frac{1498}{\pi}, \infty)$. We find this expression vanishes at two $R$. By the discussion above, we can place the 4 cites on two spheres, one for each radii.

The corresponding radius and sample location for the cities are:

$$
\begin{cases}
R   &\approx 571.164553{\rm mi}\\
q_0 &= (0^\circ,0^\circ)\\
q_1 &\approx (111.5491^\circ,0^\circ),\\
q_2 &\approx ( 96.3014^\circ,79.8187^\circ),\\
q_3 &\approx ( 81.5553^\circ, 152.2807^\circ)
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ OR }\quad
\begin{cases}
R   &\approx 693.660559{\rm mi}\\
q_0 &= (0^\circ,0^\circ)\\
q_1 &\approx (91.8503^\circ,0),\\
q_2 &\approx ( 79.2952^\circ,63.5359^\circ),\\
q_3 &\approx ( 67.1531^\circ, 126.1082^\circ).
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Part III** - How about the surface of a hyperboloid?

The answer is NO. We cannot realize the supplied distances on a hyperbolic plane,
no matter what Gaussian curvature it has.

Let $K = -\frac{1}{r^2}$ be the Gaussian curvature of the hyperbolic plane.
Let $q_0, q_1, q_2, q_4$ be any $4$ points on the hyperbolic plane.
Let $d_{ij}$ be the distance between them and $\displaystyle\;\alpha_{ij} = \frac{d_{ij}}{r}$.

We can compute the angles $\phi_{jk} = \angle q_j q_0 q_k$ using [Hyperbolic law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines)
$$\cosh\alpha_{jk}
= \cosh\alpha_{0j}\cosh\alpha_{0k} - \sinh\alpha_{0j}\sinh\alpha_{0k} \cos(\phi_{jk})$$

Let $i, j, k$ be any permutation of $1, 2, 3$ with $j < k$. If we define
$e_1, e_2, e_3$ by

$$e_i = \frac{\cosh\alpha_{0j}\cosh\alpha_{0k} - \cosh\alpha_{jk}}{\sinh\alpha_{0j}\sin\alpha_{0k}}$$

we find $\cos\phi_{i} = e_{jk}$. Repeat essentially the same argument as the spherical case, we find $e_1, e_2, e_3$ once again satisfy:

$$1 - e_1^2 - e_2^2 - e_3^2 + 2e_1e_2e_3 = 0$$

However, if we use the supplied distances and compute the value of LHS as a function of $r$, we find LHS is non-zero for all positive $r$. This implies we cannot realized the distances on a hyperbolic plane, no matter what Gaussian curvature it has.

Comment: Very thorough and clever, thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm misisng something, but at the end of part I you state that the distances cannot be Euclidean distances in $\mathbb{R}^3$, while In part II you embed the point on the surface of a sphere ($S^2$). These two statements seem contradictory -- what prevents me from embedding the $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Toffomat You can embed $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not isometrically. The distances at hand cannot be realized as euclidean distances. However, they can be realized as geodesic distances (ie. length of shortest curve connecting two points) on spheres of suitable radii.

Comment: Ah, OK. Clear now.